# How to set memory for the VM in IntelliJ? Do I have to set Tomcat memory options separately?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, intellij-idea

I'm doing some benchmarking and I want to know how to set memory for both IntelliJ and Tomcat.

In the bottom right corner I see 98M of 147M in IntelliJ, what is that for?

How do I know if I have allocated tomcat enough memory?

Comment: how is tomcat related to intellij?

Comment: btw, setting memory is the same for both using -Xmx and -Xms options when you start the JVM.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set memory options for IntelliJ itself in its VM options file.

- OS X: `Contents/info.plist` (embedded in the app's directory)
- Linux: `bin/idea.vmoptions`
- Windows: `(install dir/)bin/idea.exe.vmoptions` for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.1\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`

As of IntelliJ 12, for OS X:

- The file `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/bin/idea.vmoptions` should be copied to `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/idea.vmoptions`

This is as per [JetBrains' DOC-197](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-197) linked to by CrazyCoder.

The memory indicator shows used/max memory.

You know if you've allocated TC enough memory if it doesn't run out, and/or doesn't hiccup due to a large GC, and/or doesn't thrash swapping. Tomcat memory settings are configured in the Tomcat run configuration where it says "VM options".

Comment: so when running apache bench, where should I be looking to see these #'s for tomcat? is there a profiler for tomcat?

Comment: I'm on Mac (Lion), can't seem to find that file?

Comment: @Blankman Under OS X it's in `Contents/info.plist` as one of the VMOptions.

Comment: IntelliJ 2018 on this date for me on Mac is at:
`/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions`

Answer (score 3):

I d some problems to set the memory :
So i m using this settings for my vm :

```
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-server
-XX:NewSize=128m
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The question was what the memory statistics in the bottom-right actually mean, and how to tell if enough memory is allocated. Your VM options, while they may work great for you, do not explain what they actually mean or how you decided they were correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change three lines in your VM Options

Help->Edit Custom VM Options. Replace the first three lines by :

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
```

It's good numbers if you have 8-12Go in your machine.