# Failed make using IntelliJ, JBoss due to multiple configuration issues including Pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss, pom.xml

### Introduction

I have inherited a project that I am able to build using the maven command `mvn clean install -DskipTests`. However, I am not able to `make` using the `inteliJ` button. I am able to deploy the project using `Remote debugging` but I am not able to hotswap new code in/out due to `make not working`.

### Errors during make

When I run make I get a series of errors such as:
[image]

### Older Maven Version

I have been told to use an older version of `maven`, specifically `3.0.3` .
I have gone to the settings `for the current project` and manually set maven `3.0.3` as the default.

[image]

- **Question 1)** Is there a chance this does not apply to the sub directories? Should I change my system path variable and set the old maven as the system default?

### Red Highlighting in POM.XML

I am seeing that `InteliJ` is highlighting a `pom.xml` in one of the sub-modules for errors. This code has been committed by colleagues so it is strange that there would be errors.

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

- **Question 2)** Could Maven be the issue here? Or could there legitimately be an error in the `POM.xml`?

### Maven > Reimport does not solve the issue

Additionally, running `Maven > re-import` does not solve the issue.

### Updating Indices

I tried selecting the proposed option to `Update Maven Indices`. This has brought up the following dialogs and is downloading in the background from both the maven servers but also a private `artifactory`.

[image]
[image]

The indices were taking too long to update so I invalidated the cache/restarted and will try again as proposed @ [Intelli J IDEA takes forever to update indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991561/intelli-j-idea-takes-forever-to-update-indices) .

### Summary of Questions

- **Question 1)** Is there a chance this does not apply to the sub directories? Should I change my system path variable and set the old maven as the system default?
- **Question 2)** Could Maven be the issue here? Or could there legitimately be an error in the `POM.xml`?

### Update

Indices finished downloading after some time. 
I removed some of the problematic entries in the `pom.xml` and the project now is not red-underlying the various packages that they do not exist.

I am starting to believe the `pom.xml`was problematic. However, if someone downloads the dependencies/indices, then the problem no longer appears.

### Update - Remove Module

I talked with a colleague and he said the specific modules are no longer used (even if they do include faulty `pom.xml` files). I was told to right click the module and select "remove module". This pretty much stopped the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with a colleague and he said the specific modules are no longer used (even if they do include faulty pom.xml files). I was told to right click the module and select "remove module". This pretty much stopped the problem.