# Pycharm background tasks taking forever

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I am new to pycharm and I am having trouble to run a simple file which is just to import pandas. I am having following issues:

1. Whenever, I open the project, "Scanning files to index" takes
   forever.
2. I can see that in indexing, it is using packages/files from
   Anaconda2 and that is why it takes forever for my program to run.

I have already tried to make certain folder "Excluded" as described here [PyCharm 4.0.5 hangs on 'scanning files to index' background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030682/pycharm-4-0-5-hangs-on-scanning-files-to-index-background-task)
I have also deleted the "Caches" folder as described here [Intelli J IDEA takes forever to update indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991561/intelli-j-idea-takes-forever-to-update-indices)

[Pycharm Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDyxt.jpg)

Comment: I think you will have to wait for this to run once, or you have to uninstall some of your big packages (Anaconda seems to be the one to slow it down)

Comment: Could you please create a ticket in [PyCharms bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) and attach `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...**? There should be some hits.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm indexes your python environment as well as your project folders. This is normal when first changing either of these. If it occurs more frequently:

1. View the end of the log that @Pavel mentioned in **Help | Show Log in Explorer**.
2. Replicate the command that is stalling the scan and fix any errors.

In my case the package scanning stalled with a vague `[y/N]` as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ollbJ.jpg). Searching the log I found the following conda.exe command:

`Command line: C:\Users\<User>\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe list -p C:/Users/<User>/anaconda3/envs/py38 -e`

Running this on the command line gave me a more detailed description of my environment error and how to fix it.